# "Invalid predicate: nil RHS" for second argument in NSPredicate format

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

This is my `NSPredicate`:

```
print(searchTextField.text!)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "student.schoolClass.id = %d AND (book.title CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR student.username CONTAINS[cd] %@)", currentSchoolClass.id, searchTextField.text!, searchTextField.text!)
```

The next thing I do is:

```
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
print(fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate!)
try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch() //here is the crash
```

The console output is:

```
j  
student.schoolClass.id == 1 AND (book.title CONTAINS[cd] nil OR student.username CONTAINS[cd] "j")
```

And crash info is:

```
CRASH: Invalid predicate: nil RHS
```

Isn't it weird?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On all current iOS and OS X platforms, the C `int` is a 32-bit integer,
and that is what the `%d` format expects on the variable argument list.
If you pass a 64-bit integer then reading the next variable argument
will read the extra 4 zero bytes.

The following table shows which format is for which integer type:

```
  Format   C type          Swift type
  -----------------------------------
  %d       int             Int32
  %ld      long int        Int
  %lld     long long int   Int64
```

and similarly for the unsigned types.

Alternatively, convert the integer to a `NSNumber` object and use
the `%@` format, this works
for integers of all sizes. Example:

```
let value = 1234
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "value = %@", value as NSNumber)
```

Comment: Do you think? Because indeed, it works on **iPad Pro**, and doesnt work on **iPad 4**. Does it explain anything?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: What does not work on an iPad 4, my suggestion or your code?

Comment: My code from the question. But it looks like there is no problem with `schoolClass.id` which is **Int64** but with simple string.

Comment: I think its weird... one takes a value and another takes nil ... with `txtfield.text` ... how ???

Comment: @Bhavin: The `%d` format expects a 32-bit integer. If you pass a 64-bit integer to the variable argument list then reading the next argument will get the extra zero bytes.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: For an `Int64` argument, use `%lld`, that should work on all platforms.

Comment: @MartinR, you are really smart guy:) It works. so assuming: `%d` for `Int` and `Int16`, `%ld` for `Int32` and `%lld` for `Int64`, right? I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: Not quite. I have updated the answer with a table.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting nil as there is nothing in searchTextField.

So that only it will shows as nil in predicate.

Check the value in the textfield.

Hope it helps..

Comment: I updated the question, there is correct value of `searchTextField.text!`