# Generic NSPredicate

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to create a function which returns a `NSPredicate`.

Currently I have:

```
func predicate(value: String, op: String, predicate: String) -> [NSPredicate] {
    return [NSPredicate(format: "\(value) \(op) %@", predicate)]
}

func predicate(value: String, op: String, predicate: Int) -> [NSPredicate] {
    return [NSPredicate(format: "\(value) \(op) %d", predicate)]
}

func predicate(value: String, op: String, predicate: NSManagedObject) -> [NSPredicate] {
    return [NSPredicate(format: "\(value) \(op) %@", predicate)]
}

func predicate(value: String, op: String, predicate: Date) -> [NSPredicate] {
    return [NSPredicate(format: "\(value) \(op) %@", predicate)]
}
```

Which seems a bit excessive. So I've been trying to merge them together and create a generic function:

```
func predicate<T: CVarArg>(value: String, op: String, predicate: T) -> [NSPredicate] {
    return [NSPredicate(format: "\(value) \(op) %@", predicate)]
}
```

This works except when `T` is an `Int`. For that I need to use `%d`. I tried to add the line:

```
let symbol = T is SignedInteger ? "%d" : "%@"
```

But this is giving me an error:

> ...can only be used as a generic constraint...

Then I thought I could create the function with a `where` clause:

```
func ... -> [NSPredicate] where T: SignedInteger { ... }
```

But then I don't know how to make it accept for `Date`, `String` and `NSManagedObject`.

**Question:**
How can I create a generic function which can distinguish between an `Int` and "others"?

Comment: To be honest, I fail to see the usefulness of such a function. What is the advantage of `predicate(value: "key", op: "=", predicate: 123)` over `NSPredicate(format: "key = %d", 123)`?

Comment: @MartinR The examples have been simplified. Originally it's a protocol for my `NSManagedObject` with a nested `enum` so I can create a predicate easier.

Comment: Note that the correct format for integer arguments depends on the *size* of the integer type. On a 64-bit platform, `NSPredicate(format: "key = %d", Int.max)` will not give the expected result and you should use `%ld` for `Int` (== Int64) arguments.

Comment: @MartinR Forgive me for being a bit lazy (and I can't seem to find the answer yet), does that mean I should use `%ld` just to be safe instead of `%d`?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/37073412/1187415. Actually the easiest way is to convert all numbers to `NSNumber`

Comment: @HennyLee I believe it can be achieved in one function. Adding a boolean argument isThisInt which is by default set to false if you use an int just set it to true and you can then use the ternary operator within your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem using your earlier solution for having different implementations for different parameter types : **overloading**.

```
func predicate<T: CVarArg>(value: String, op: String, predicate: T) -> [NSPredicate] {
    return [NSPredicate(format: "\(value) \(op) %@", predicate)]
}

func predicate(value: String, op: String, predicate: Int) -> [NSPredicate] {
    return [NSPredicate(format: "\(value) \(op) %d", predicate)]
}
```

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I could do it without overloading. I have been considering your answer too but was worrying about when using an `Int`, it would use the first function. I realize now that won't happen since it will automatically use the second function once an `Int` is used.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. This is the optimal approach since code is shared as much as it can be, but not more.