# Swift string %d formatter converting large Int into a negative number

Tags: swift

I have no clue what's going on here but I want to format a string with a large integer in it. This value is a swift `Int`. Yet when I use the `%d` string formatter, all I get is a negative, random value.

```
let troublesomeIntVal: Int = 222773803005739009
print(String(format: "this is wrong: %d", troublesomeIntVal))
print(String(format: "but this works: %ld", troublesomeIntVal))
```

Output:

```
this is wrong: -244613119
but this works: 222773803005739009
```

Comment: Do you understand what %d and %ld mean? Do you understand why adding the l modifier makes it work?

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073099/invalid-predicate-nil-rhs-for-second-argument-in-nspredicate-format.

Answer (score 3):

Following https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html `%d` is a "Signed 32-bit integer" - your value does not fit into 32-bit, it overflows the 32-bit range.

`%ld` on the other hand handles `NSInteger`, which are 64bit, which is the size the swift `Int` has as well.

Comment: FYI - `NSInteger` is 32-bits on 32-bit devices and it is 64-bits on 64-bit devices. `%ld` handles `long` data types, not `NSInteger`.

Comment: Yep I saw that @luk2302 but when I print `Int.max`, that number is larger than the value I'm using.  So if the number I'm using is less than Int.max then what's going on.  Also @rmaddy I did see that %ld is for long types, but it seemed to be the only one that worked.

Comment: @rmaddy: `long int` is 32- or 64-bit as well and has the same size as NSInteger, at least on all current Apple platforms and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, adding to @luk2302's answer, the morale of the story is if you're using Int in Swift, don't use the `%d` string formatter, use `%ld` **in case it is a 64 bit integer**.

```
let troublesomeIntVal1: Int = 222773803005739009
let troublesomeIntVal2: Int = 222773803005739009
print(String(format: "%d", troublesomeIntVal1))
print(String(format: "%ld", troublesomeIntVal2))
```

prints

```
-244613119
222773803005739009
```