# How to use both predicates and sortdecriptor in coredata

Tags: swift, core-data

I am using 'sortdescriptor' for fetching 'nsmutablearray',its sorted by creation date but the problem its is not filtering by predicate.I want to apply both sort and filter.i have tried with following

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    let pre:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %d", 100)
    fetchRequest.predicate = pre
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
```

Comment: Can you share more details? For example, what is the structure of your entity object? What is the results are you getting with the current code?

Comment: What output do you get and what to you expect? Try `"id == %ld"` (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/37073412/1187415)

Comment: what is the entityName for which you want to fetch result

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
change <Message> to your entityModel


let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Message>.init(entityName: "Message")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "date", ascending: false)]
let predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "id = %@","100")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```