# Localizable.strings works for String, but not for Double and Integer 32

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization, swiftui-text

As a Swift newbie I am trying to localize [a simple SwiftUI and Core Data project](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/Tops1) at Github:

[image: screenshot]

I have added the following [en.lproj/Localizable.strings](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/Tops1/Tops1/en.lproj/Localizable.strings) file to my project:

```
"elo-rating %@" = "Elo rating: %@";
"avg-time %@" = "Average time: %@";
"avg-score %@" = "Average score: %@";
```

And in my custom SwiftUI View [TopRow.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/Tops1/Tops1/Views/TopRow.swift) I am trying to use the above 3 keys:

```
struct TopRow: View {
    let topEntity:TopEntity
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            DownloadImage(url: topEntity.photo ?? "TODO")
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            Spacer()
            Text(topEntity.given ?? "Unknown Person")
                .frame(minWidth: 60, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("elo-rating \(topEntity.elo)")
                Text("avg-time \(topEntity.avg_time ?? "")")
                Text("avg-score \(topEntity.avg_score)")
            }.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
        }.font(.footnote)
    }
}
```

However only the middle Text with average time is localized properly:

[image: emulator]

I have also tried the following lines with no success:

```
"elo-rating %@" = "Elo rating: %ld";
"elo-rating %ld" = "Elo rating: %ld";
"elo-rating %lld" = "Elo rating: %lld";
```

It just does not work :-) Please help me to find my error.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37073412/1187415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `%d`. `%d` is for an integer type

```
"elo-rating %d" = "Elo rating: %d";
```

For Average score, Use `%lf`.

```
"avg-score %lf" = "Average score: %lf";
```